# redirect to a page with pk on django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

This funtion is to update an order, i would like to be redirected to the customer profile page where i can find all this customer's orders. on the costumer profile i have all orders listed with option to modify or delete. i would like to modify and to redirected to the costumer profile page which the url is :

```
path("customer_profile/<int:pk>/", views.Customer_profile, name="customer_profile")

def OrderUpdate(request, pk):
order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
form = OrderForm(instance=order)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('orders')

context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'orders/order_form.html', context)
```

Comment: What is the primary key of the profile? Does the `user` has some `.profile`?

Comment: costumer X make orders, all orders are linked to this costumers. when i update this order for ex, i would like to be redirected to the customer_profile page, not orders page

Comment: but then your `Order` has a `ForeignKey` or something to a `Customer`? Can you share relevant parts of your `Order` model?

Comment: yes, order has a foreignkey to customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to the `customer_profile` of the `Order`. If the `ForeignKey` from `Order` to `Customer` is named `customer`, you can thus redirect to:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def OrderUpdate(request, pk):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
    form = OrderForm(instance=order)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('customer_profile', pk=order.customer_id)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'orders/order_form.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.